# Haskell check if a value in monad exists

Tags: haskell

I'm wondering if there is an equivalent or something for `null` from lists generalized for monads. At the moment I'm trying to find erroneous values with `== mzero`. But this kind of check provokes false positives since `mzero /= Left "foo"` applies.

Is there an elegant way to express what I want in standard libraries?

Comment: It seems like your questions got interrupted at some

Comment: @Zeta Yes, I accidently hit the return key on my keyboard. ^^

Comment: I think there would be some issues with what is seen as "erroneous values" (I think you mean some kind of error/empty-condition) for all monads - can you come up with some definition/laws that are different from those of `MonadPlus`?

Comment: To make a stupid example: what should such a condition be for the `Identity` monad?

Comment: @Carsten I would not create an instance for the Identity monad. That is what I would do. I just thought about an additional layer featuring those laws. If the standard libraries provide such a layer I would use it and write it on my own otherwise.

Comment: well maybe I missunderstood you - I somehow interpreted it as you wanting a way that works for *all* monads ... sorry

Comment: @Carsten Don't worry. Maybe just I wasn't that clear in my question as I thought I was.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The notion "contains a value" isn't captured by the `Monad` typeclass. After all, a `Monad` only gives you something to sequence (`>>=`) actions (bind the previous result). And `MonadPlus` gives you a way to "shortcut" a computation with `mzero` (have a look at the laws and `mplus`).

However, being able to contain one or many values usually goes hand in hand with being able to fold all those values together into something. And indeed, `Data.Foldable` contains a function conveniently also called `null`:

```
> import qualified Data.Foldable as F
> 
> showAndTell :: (Show (t a), Foldable t) => t a -> IO ()
> showAndTell k =
>   putStrLn $ "  F.null (" ++ show k ++ ") is " ++ show (F.null k)

> main = do
>   putStrLn "Using F.null on 'empty' things:"
>   showAndTell $ (Left "Error" :: Either String Int)
>   showAndTell $ (Nothing :: Maybe Integer)
>   showAndTell $ ([]      :: [Double])
> 
>   putStrLn ""
>   putStrLn "Using F.null on 'filled' things:"
>   showAndTell $ (Right 123 :: Either String Integer)
>   showAndTell $ (Just  123 :: Maybe Integer)
>   showAndTell $ ([1,2,3] :: [Int])
```

Result:

```
Using F.null on 'empty' things:
  F.null (Left "Error") is True
  F.null (Nothing) is True
  F.null ([]) is True

Using F.null on 'filled' things:
  F.null (Right 123) is False
  F.null (Just 123) is False
  F.null ([1,2,3]) is False
```

So what you're looking for is part of `Foldable`, not `Monad`. This will only work on GHC 7.10 or higher, since `Data.Foldable.null` was introduces in base 4.8.0.0. If you're stuck with an older version of GHC, you can use

```
> isEmpty :: F.Foldable t => t a -> Bool
> isEmpty = F.foldr (\_ _ -> False) True
```

Comment: I'm afraid you don't get backward compatibility, because `null` wasn't generalized to `Foldable` at all until GHC 7.10.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Whoops. I didn't notice I was on my GHC 7.10 PC.

Comment: @Zeta Don't worry, I'm using 7.10 too. Thanks for pointing me out to the Foldable type class. That's exactly what I'm looking for. :)

Comment: `Foldable` did, however, contain enough methods that you could *define* the generalized `null`, e.g. as `null . F.toList`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Or `F.foldr (\_ _ -> False) True` (I think that's the default implementation in `foldr`). One could also use `data IsEmpty = Empty | NonEmpty` with a proper `Monoid` instance and `foldMap`. I guess there are many ways to implement `Data.Foldable.null` :D.

Comment: @Zeta: The `Monoid` you are looking for is `Any`.

Comment: There is a type class for Empty - https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.13/docs/Control-Lens-Empty.html - but in my opinion it is not the correct generalisation for the OP if he's working with monads which can fail.

Comment: @drquicksilver I went with `Foldable`. I can live with the fact that only GHC 7.10+ is supported. `Empty` seems to be quite nice but I guess `Foldable` applies better in case of monads. But thanks for pointing me out!

Answer (score 5):

I cannot on the spot remember any simple function that works for all the monads `Maybe`,  `Either e`, `MaybeT m` and `ExceptT e m`, which are the main monads I can think of that have "erroneous values".

Since GHC 7.10, `null` actually has been generalized (to `Foldable`), so it works on the first two.

For the last three (`Either e` works with both methods) and transformed versions of them, you can probably use the [`catchError`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Error-Class.html#v:catchError) function.

(Although the last two *have* `Foldable` instances, their `null` does the wrong thing.)

Answer (score 5):

Definitely not from outside the monad. If you're searching for something like `nonEmpty :: MonadPlus m => m a -> Bool` then it's impossible.

You'd need to actually run the monadic computation to find out whether it's "empty". But the monad might need some sort of input to run (e.g. things like `State` or even just `Reader`), and in the extreme case of `IO` you can't run the monad at all from outside. Now those examples aren't `MonadPlus` on their own AFAICR, but augment them with failure (e.g. `MaybeT`) and suddenly there's an obvious definition of what it means for them to be "empty", but the same restrictions still apply. Since an unknown monad could be one of those, you can't get any information out.

A possible signature might be `nonEmpty :: MonadPlus m => m a -> m Bool` (although I'm not sure that that has a sensible implementation either). But I don't think that's what you're after, since it doesn't actually generalise `null`; you'd end up retiring `[False]` or `[True]` for lists (or possibly even `[True, True, True, ...]` with the same number of elements as the input), which is a bit weird.

I think monads are on the wrong "axis of generalisation" for `null`; you want an abstraction that better characterises containers than `Monad` does (lots of monads *are* containers, but so are lots of other things that are very different, so code that works on arbitrary monads can't assume container-like properties). Generalising to `Foladable` as happened in GHC-7.10 seems a pretty good bet. You could probably make a `CanBeEmpty` type class that admits a few more things than `Foldable`; I don't know that such a thing exists already though.

Comment: `Foldable` was completely sufficient. I did not know that null has been generalized with GHC 7.10 and I did not want to implement something like `Foldable` if there is a type class that is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic thing to do is not to try to detect the zero directly, but to provide the behaviour you want in case of zero.

This is what `mplus` or equivalently (in recent Preludes) `<|>` do; it chains an action to run in the case that the first action fails. This is the same as `catchError` on those Monads which `catchError` supports. It is analogous to the common idiom in shell or perl programming `foo || bar` meaning run foo and then run bar if foo failed.

Beware in the list monad that it will run all the options though because that is how the list monad is designed to work, modelling 'multiple possibilities'.

I frequently use `<|>` on `MaybeT` or `EitherT` to model left-biased choice, i.e. "try all of these alternatives in turn until one succeeds".

Beware that using `<|>` for `EitherT` does discard the error message (because it turns a failing computation into a succeeding one); if you want to save the error message and process it somehow it is, again, `catchError` you wanted.